# Count entries across three tables based on month in SQL or LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot, pivot-table

I would like to extract some data from three tables in a SQL Server 2005 database.  While this can surely be done in code, it seems like this could be done reasonably well in SQL (bonus points for LINQ!).

Basically, I would like to know **for each month how many calls and meetings each employee has held with each of our clients**.  Something like this:

```
Employee GUID   Customer GUID   Jan calls   Jan mtgs   Feb calls      Feb mtgs...
[a guid]        [another guid]  5           0          7              3
```

The data is spread across three tables.  For simplicity's sake, let's just show the relevant columns:

**Communications Table**

```
[CommunicationId]  (PK, uniqueidentifier)
[Type]             (nvarchar(1)) ('C' for call, 'M' for meeting, etc.)
[Date]             (datetime)
```

**Person-Communication Table**

```
[PersonId]         (PK, FK, uniqueidentifier) (Can contain GUIDs for employees or clients, see Person Table below)
[CommunicationId]  (PK, FK, uniqueidentifier)
```

**Person Table**

```
[PersonId]         (PK, uniqueidentifier)
[Type]             (nvarchar(1)) ('E' for employee, 'C' for customer)
```

So, **the questions**:

1. Can this be done in SQL without horrendous code or big performance problems?
2. If so, how?  I'd even settle for a good high-level strategy.  I'm guessing [pivots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) will play a big role here (particularly the "Complex PIVOT Example").  [DATEPART(MONTH, Date)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) seems like a good method for partitioning the communications by month along the lines of:

> ```
> SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, Date), COUNT(*) 
> FROM [CommunicationTable]
> WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Date) = '2009'
> GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, Date)
> ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, Date)
> ```

... which gets me the number of communications in each month in 2009:

```
1    2871
2    2639
3    3654
4    2751
5    1773
6    2575
7    2906
8    2398
9    2621
10   2638
11   1705
12   2290
```

Comment: @Hogan: `uniqueidentifier` datatype does not imply `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: @Hogan: `uniqueidentifier` is SQL Server's term for a GUID.  Multiple persons can be associated with multiple communications (but only once, e.g.,  being associated with a phone call three times is nonsensical and not allowed).

Comment: Yikes!  I take it back... never mind.

Comment: I think you might want to replace data type `nvarchar(1)` with `char(1)`: you do not need to keep the length, and definitely do not need to support more then ASCII. Especially since you search on those columns, you might have indices that include them, size of which will have impact on the performance (and generally table size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non PIVOT, CASE using syntax:

```
WITH summary AS (
      SELECT emp.personid AS emp_guid,
             cust.personid AS cust_guid,
             DATEPART(MONTH, ct.date) AS mon, 
             ct.type,
             COUNT(*) AS num_count
        FROM COMMUNICATIONTABLE ct
   LEFT JOIN PERSON_COMMUNICATION pc ON pc.communicationid = ct.communicationid
        JOIN PERSON emp ON emp.personid = pc.personid
                       AND emp.type = 'E'
        JOIN PERSON cust ON cust.personid = p.personid
                        AND cust.type = 'C'
       WHERE ct.date BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-12-31'
    GROUP BY emp.personid, cust.personid, DATEPART(MONTH, ct.ate), ct.type)
SELECT s.emp_guid,
       s.cust_guid,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.mon = 1 AND s.type = 'C' THEN s.num_count ELSE 0 END) AS "Jan calls",
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.mon = 1 AND s.type = 'M' THEN s.num_count ELSE 0 END) AS "Jan mtgs",
       ... --Copy/Paste two lines, update the month check... and the col alias
  FROM summary s
GROUP BY s.emp_guid, s.cust_guid
```

Use `WHERE ct.date BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-12-31'` because `WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Date) = '2009'` can't use an index if one exists on the `date` column.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: See my answer -- won't this get totals based on Person and Customer, or did I mess something up?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Yeah in the Communications table it is, but not in PersonCommunication table -- I guess I'm lost on what you mean by summation.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: You need one more group by on the outer select (`group by emp_guid, cust_guid`) and a `sum()` for each case or you will get a many rows when you want one,you will get one row for call total and one row for mtg total for each month in the range.

Comment: @Hogan: Not sarcastic at all.  I can't get better if there's no feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started I did one month for one year for you, you can also add in the date range restrictions:

```
SELECT PE.PersonID as EmployeeID,PC2.PersonID as CustomerID,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, C.[Date]) = 1 
           AND DATEPART(YEAR,C.[Date]) = 2009 
           AND C.[type] = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Jan 2009 Calls]
FROM PersonTable PE
JOIN PersonCommunicationTable PC ON PE.PersonID = PC.PersonID
JOIN CommunicationsTable C ON PC.CommunicationID = C.CommunicationID
JOIN PersonCommunicationTable PC2 ON PC.CommunicationID = PC2.CommunicationID AND NOT PC2.PersonID = PC.PersonID 
WHERE PE.Type = 'E'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reasonably equivalent solution using Pivot.

```
Declare @Comm TABLE
(
    [CommunicationId] uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [Type]  nvarchar(1), -- ('C' for call, 'M' for meeting, etc.)
    [Date] datetime
)

Declare @Person TABLE
(
    [PersonId]  uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [Type]      Nvarchar(1) -- ('E' for employee, 'C' for customer)
)
Declare @PersonComm TABLE
(
    [PersonId] uniqueidentifier, -- (Can contain GUIDs for employees or clients, see Person Table below)
    [CommunicationId] uniqueidentifier
)

INSERT INTO @Person(Type)
Select 'C' UNION ALL Select 'E'  UNION ALL Select 'C' UNION ALL Select 'E'

INSERT INTO @Comm([Type],[Date])
Select 'C', '01/04/2010' UNION ALL Select 'C', '01/04/2010'
UNION ALL Select 'C', '04/04/2010' UNION ALL Select 'C', '05/01/2010'
UNION ALL Select 'C', '08/04/2009' UNION ALL Select 'C', '09/01/2009'
UNION ALL Select 'M', '01/04/2010' UNION ALL Select 'M', '03/20/2010'
UNION ALL Select 'M', '04/04/2010' UNION ALL Select 'M', '06/01/2010'
UNION ALL Select 'M', '04/10/2009' UNION ALL Select 'M', '04/10/2009'

INSERT INTO @PersonComm
Select  E.PersonID ,  Comm.[CommunicationId]
FROM    @Person E 
        ,@Comm Comm
Where E.[Type] = 'E' 

INSERT INTO @PersonComm
Select  E.PersonID ,  Comm.[CommunicationId]
FROM    @Person E 
        ,@Comm Comm
Where E.[Type] = 'C' 

Select  EmployeeID, 
        ClientID,
        Year, 
        [JanuaryC] AS [Jan Calls], 
        [JanuaryM] AS [Jan Meetings],
        [FebruaryC], 
        [FebruaryM],
        [MarchC], 
        [MarchM], 
        [AprilC], 
        [AprilM], 
        [MayC], 
        [MayM], 
        [JuneC], 
        [JuneM], 
        [JulyC], 
        [JulyM],
        [AugustC], 
        [AugustM],
        [SeptemberC] ,
        [SeptemberM],
        [OctoberC] ,
        [OctoberM],
        [NovemberC],
        [NovemberM],
        [DecemberC], 
        [DecemberM]

FROM 
(
Select P.PersonId EmployeeID, Client.PersonId ClientID, YEAR(C.Date) Year, DateName(m,C.Date) Month,  COUNT(*) Amount, C.Type CommType,
       DateName(m,C.Date) + C.Type PivotColumn -- JanuaryC
FROM    @Comm C
        INNER JOIN @PersonComm PC
            ON PC.CommunicationId = C.CommunicationId
        INNER JOIN @Person P
            ON P.PersonId = PC.PersonId 
        INNER JOIN @PersonComm PCC
            ON PCC.CommunicationId = PC.CommunicationId
        INNER JOIN @Person Client
            ON Client.PersonId = PCC.PersonId AND Client.Type = 'C' 
Where P.Type = 'E'      
Group By P.PersonId, CLient.PersonId, YEAR(C.Date), DateName(m,C.Date), C.Type
) SourceTable
PIVOT (
MAX(Amount)
FOR PivotColumn IN 
    ([JanuaryC], [JanuaryM],[FebruaryC], [FebruaryM],[MarchC], [MarchM], [AprilC], [AprilM], [MayC], [MayM], [JuneC], [JuneM], [JulyC], [JulyM],
     [AugustC], [AugustM],[SeptemberC] , [SeptemberM],[OctoberC] ,[OctoberM],[NovemberC], [NovemberM], [DecemberC], [DecemberM]

)
)As PivotTable
```